# How can I open a file with a variable (array) name on php?

Tags: php, arrays, fopen, fgets, fread

I tried write a php script for taking 1 main file from server and read this file, explode it(with ":" character) and keep it a array then I write this variables in array to a txt file each new line. Then I can read this file line by line but I can't open any file with `fopen($variable, 'r');`. My variable is; `$variable = $array[1]."txt";`.

My codes;

```
<?php

$file = file("toplist.txt");

$countLine = count($file);
$userMain = array();
$userMain[0] = "Top List";
$userNames = array();
$userNames[0] = "SampleName";
for ($i=1;$i<$countLine;$i++){

    $user = explode (":",$file[$i],-1);
    $userMain[$i] = $user[0];
    echo $userMain[$i]."<br>"; //Test echo
}
$totalLn = count($userMain);
echo $totalLn;   //Echo total line.

$myFile = $userMain[1].".txt";


$fileAA = fopen($myFile,'r');

while($line = fgets($fileAA))
    $data[] = $line;

fclose($fileAA);

for ($counter = 0; $counter <= 5 ; $counter++ )
{
    echo "<i>".$data[$counter]."</i><br />";
}
?>
```

My toplist.txt file;

```
toplist:
  54df3a11-3ea0-37c4-8ec4-0fdd45f2e069: 211
```

and I have a file with a `54df3a11-3ea0-37c4-8ec4-0fdd45f2e069.txt` named.

And `54df3a11-3ea0-37c4-8ec4-0fdd45f2e069.txt` file contents;

```
name : SampleName123
destination : SampleDestination
SampleContent : SampleContent
```

I need the name line and just `SampleName123`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$contents = file_get_contents($array[1]."txt");
$rows = explode("\n",$contents);
$user = [];
foreach($rows as $row){
    $parts = explode(" : ",$row);
    $user[$parts[0]] = $parts[1];
}
```

After this parsing you can access user as an array.

```
$user['name']
```

And you can do the listing as well:

```
$file = file($user['name'].".txt"); //Reads entire file into an array
foreach($file as $row){
    echo "<i>".$row."</i><br />";
}
```

PS: It's working but need to use trim() function for taken file names from .txt file

Comment: ...
```
echo $userMain[1]; //print "54df3a11-3ea0-37c4-8ec4-0fdd45f2e069"

$contents = file_get_contents($userMain[1].".txt");
$rows = explode("\n",$contents);
echo $rows; // print "Array"
$user = [];
foreach($rows as $row){
    $parts = explode(" : ",$row);
    $user[$parts[0]] = $parts[1];
    echo $parts[0]; // no content
    echo $parts[1]; // no content
}

echo $user['name']; //no content

?>
```
It is not working on me :/

Comment: Make sure you write the correct path to file. I ran the same as you and I got correct values.

Comment: I am working on a hosting, is there a problem with hosting side? I am working on a same directory, all files in same dir.

Comment: It's working but need to use trim() function for taken file names from .txt file :)

Answer (score 0):

If the file content is always the same take the first row and use `substr($str, 0, 7);  // Outputs: SampleName123`

Comment: I can not the take first row, this is my problem :)

Comment: $f = fopen($file, 'r');
$line = fgets($f);
fclose($f);